# Link user accounts (hierarchy) with Google Identity Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity-management, google-cloud-identity

I'm planning on having family accounts and I was wondering if Google Identity Platform allows some sort of hierarchical chain across users.

Example: my family consists of three people, but I'm the one paying. I'd have full permission (edit payment, for example). I'd like to give to my spouse some sort of parental consent (if it was a streaming service, he/she could watch R rated videos), but my child can only watch PG-13 videos.

Does Google Identity Platform allow such thing? If so, where can I find more information in their documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do something by using custom claims and the admin sdk

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to-configure-custom-claims

I just added the parent account and role as custom fields